# how to grep for specific time period in a log

Tags: linux, sed, grep, logs

We work with log files that have line entries that start with a date/time format such as this:

```
20150408 13:29:28 <rest of text>
```

What would I need to do in order to `grep` for a date range?

Say like all lines that start at `20150408 13:29:28` and end at `20150408 17:55:02`?

Would `grep` be the tool for the job or would something else be better like `sed`?

Comment: I suspect that regexp will not be the *best* tool (so no grep or sed), though you could do the example. `awk` may be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certanly task can be done by `sed`

```
sed '/20150408 13:29:28/,/20150408 17:55:02/! d' log_files
```

but if lines did not have exact `20150408 13:29:28` script will print nothing and if its did not have exact `20150408 17:55:02` file will print every lines till the end.
So the better is use date compare by script:

```
limit1=$(date -d "20150408 13:29:28" +"%s")
limit2=$(date -d "20150408 17:55:02" +"%s")
while read -r logdate logtime logline
do
    logsec=$(date -d "$logdate $logtime" +"%s")
    if [ $limit1 -le $logsec -a $limit2 -ge $logsec ]
    then
        echo $logdate $logtime $logline
    fi
done < log_files
```

Comment: A few notes: The posted solution is non-standard in two respects; `date`'s `%s` and the test operator `[` with more than 4 arguments are not defined by POSIX. The pattern match is (as correctly noted) errorprone. (A similar syntax is possible with awk: `awk '/from/,/to/'`, BTW.) Since the OP's date is defined in a regular and sortable way, an awk comparison (as shown in another answer) is straightforward and most legible: `awk '$1" "$2 >= from && $1" "$2 <= to'` and (IMO) to be preferred.

Comment: @Janis First thanks to correct my mistype. Second there are not 4 arg's but *EXPR1 -a EXPR2 True if both expr1 AND expr2 are true* (from `help test`)

Comment: No, your `test` expression (or builtin in some shells; but that doesn't affect the question of POSIX complience) has 7 arguments. (See POSIX: `http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html`.) A POSIX complient version could be `if [ $limit1 -le $logsec ] && [ $limit2 -ge $logsec ]`; i.e. splitting the one `test` command in two with three argument each.

Answer (score 3):

I think `awk` could help:

```
awk 'BEGIN { sd = "20150408T13:29:28"; ed = "20150408T17:55:02"; } $1 "T" $2 >= sd && $1 "T" $2 <= ed' log
```